# adding author emails and affiliation on 2nd second line not as a footnote

Tags: latex

Latex code that i have executed, insert emails as a footnote which i want to insert under the author name or on the same line with affiliation. i have insert an image of the required format as well.

```
 \documentclass[a4,12pt,twosided,reqno]{article} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{authblk}

\title{More than one Author with different Affiliations}
\author[1]{Sadique Ahmad\thanks{ahmad01.shah@gmail.com}}
\author[1]{Awais Adnan\thanks{awaisadnan@gmail.com}}
\affil[1]{Department of Computer Science, IM|Sciences Peshawar}
\affil[2]{Department of Computer Science, IM|Sciences Peshawar}

\renewcommand\Authands{ and }

\begin{document}
  \maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: if you dont have the answer than y you giving minus...thats not fair

Comment: Or you should spend some more time on asking a good question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's easy enough to hijack the `\date` macro, or actually set `\@date` directly:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 

\title{More than one Author with different Affiliations}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@date{{%
  \vspace{-\baselineskip}%
  \large\centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
    First Author\textsuperscript{1} \\
    \normalsize first.author@email.com
  \end{tabular}%
  \quad and\quad
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
    Second Author\textsuperscript{2} \\
    \normalsize second.author@email.com
  \end{tabular}

  \bigskip

  \textsuperscript{1}Some Department, Some University\par
  \textsuperscript{2}Some Department, Some University

  \bigskip

  \today
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Since I've set the `\@date` to include paragraphs (having blank lines and/or explicit `\par`), it has to be defined using `\long`; `\renewcommand` does this by default.

Fake associations with an affiliation is achieved using `\textsuperscript{<stuff>}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot...u r code is absolutely working well. Thanks again

Comment: Any chance you know how I can combine this with an asterisk indicating shared authorship? Thanks!

Comment: @jmb: You'd have to provide a visual of what you mean by that. Also, I'd suggest asking on [tex.se] rather, and perhaps add a reference to this post.